# Python logging ignore escape (\033) for file handler

Tags: python, logging

I'm using logging to log some information.
I used both `FileHandler` and `StreamHandler` in my logger, to output the message in the console and saved to a specific file.
In the console, to highlight some important message, I used `\033`. But this word also add into my log file and shown a weird symbol. Following is my currently usage example

```
logger = logging.getLogger('SayHello')
file_hdlr = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
file_hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
console_hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()
console_hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_hdlr)
logger.addHandler(console_hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('\033[1;31mHello World\033[0m')
```

Output in console:
Hello World (in red)

Output in log file:
[1;31mHello World[0m

How can I ignore the `\033` and other color code in my file handler? Should I override the `FileHandler` class? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you like the `logger.info('\033[1;31mHello World\033[0m')` to log just `Hello World`?

Comment: Note that the simple "fix" is to read the logs with a viewer that interprets the escapes properly. For example, if your terminal can properly interpret the escapes, then using ``less -R`` to view the file should work.

Comment: @np8 I want the console to show the message in colour and no control code in my log file

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes! `less` can display the file properly. Not sure if there is any plugin in `gedit` to handle these control codes?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075911/debugging-a-python-function-to-remove-ansi-codes

Comment: Currently I revised the `emit` in `StreamHandler`, if the stream is a file instead of `stderr`, then I will ignore the control sequences. It can solve the problem, but I know that was not a good solution :(

Answer (score 1):

After several hours tracing, I found that `FileHandler` also inherited from `StreamHandler`. `FileHandler.emit` call `StreamHandler.emit` to write message into the file.
To ignore the control sequences in the message, I have to override both `FileHandler` and `StreamHandler`, says `CustomFileHandler` and `CustomStreamHandler`, respectively.
`CustomFileHandler.emit` call `CustomStreamHandler.emit` to write the message, where we have to remove the control sequences in it. With the help of regular expression, this should be easy to find them.